# Speed up for nested for loop using apply function

Tags: r, apply, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am not good in using apply family of functions.

I want to use apply family of functions instead of following type of nested loop iterated by 9076 x 9076 times for computation speed up. Minimal reproducible data is given below. Please help.

Data:

```
data = structure(list(C1 = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("GO:0001525", 
"GO:0001869", "GO:0002576", "GO:0003723", "GO:0005515"), class = "factor"), 
    C2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("GO:0002020", 
    "GO:0003674", "GO:0003727", "GO:0005515", "GO:0005829"), class = "factor"), 
    C3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("", "GO:0002020", 
    "GO:0005576", "GO:0005886"), class = "factor"), C4 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("", "GO:0002576", "GO:0005737", 
    "GO:0008201"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A1BG", 
"A1CF", "A2M", "AAGAB", "AAMP"))
```

Code:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("GO.db", version = "3.8")
BiocManager::install("GOSemSim", version = "3.8")
BiocManager::install("org.Hs.eg.db", version = "3.8")
BiocManager::install("annotate", version = "3.8")

install.packages("cluster")
install.packages("RUnit")

# download csbl.go_1.4.1.tar.gz from http://csbi.ltdk.helsinki.fi/csbl.go/

# R CMD INSTALL csbl.go_1.4.1.tar.gz

library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(GO.db)
library(GOSemSim)


mat=matrix(,5,5)  %actual mat=matrix(,9076,9076)
hsGO <- godata('org.Hs.eg.db', ont="MF")

for (i in 1:5) %actual for(i in 1:9076)
{
for (j in 1:5) %actual for(j in 1:9076)
{
   a=as.matrix(data[i,1:ncol(data)])
   b=as.matrix(data[j,1:ncol(data)])
   a=a[a!=""]
   b=b[b!=""]
   mat[i,j]=mgoSim(a,b, semData=hsGO, measure="Wang", combine="BMA")
  }
  print(paste("ith Iteration: ",i))
}
```

Here I wish to execute the mgoSim function using apply family of function for computation speed up as using 9076 x 9076 nested for loop, I am not getting result.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think that loop itself is fine, you are effectively recycling a and b mat is also an matrix of appropriate size for the loop, I prefer to change the 1:5  to be something like vector = 5, seq_len(vector), my tip would be to look into multi threaded solutions see the future libraries.

Comment: I can't run tests on your code because the libraries are not on cran.

Comment: The packages all seem to be from bioconductor

Comment: @Bruno data contains 9076 rows and 870 columns and actual loop is like `for (i in 1:9076) { for (j in 1:9076) { a=as.matrix(data[i,2:ncol(data)]) b=as.matrix(data[j,2:ncol(data)]) a=a[a!=""] b=b[b!=""] mat[i,j]=mgoSim(a,b, semData=hsGO, measure="Wang", combine="BMA") } }` Thus unable to execute in a i5 machine. I have edited the code above...

Comment: I can only speed up your code by 4 times max, use library(foreach), use a cluster library(doMC) > registerDoMC(4), then change your for loops to foreach(i=1:9076) %dopar% {... see more at: https://www.r-bloggers.com/parallel-r-loops-for-windows-and-linux/

Comment: @Bruno Thanks. But I have tried that too... Even I am unable to get results.

Comment: I can't use the function godata

Comment: @Bruno `library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(GO.db)
library(GOSemSim)`

Comment: Please edit your question with clarifications and code. Code in comments is really impossible to read.

Comment: @divibisan questions contains all information. Comments codes are not required. Just added to reply.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the contributors to GOSemSim (my contribution was to speed up the internal code process).

If I understood your code, you want to compare the functionality of your genes in the molecular function subontology.

You need a vector of the genes or GO terms for the comparison, I also used the `mgeneSim` function to compare the genes instead of making yourself the comparison of the GO terms. (If you want to compare the go terms it can be done too

```
genes <- rownames(data)
genes_entrez <- mapIds(org.Hs.eg.db, keys = genes, keytype = "SYMBOL", column = "ENTREZID")
m <- mgeneSim(g,  semData=hsGO, measure="Wang", combine="BMA")
colnames(m) <- rownames(data)
colnames(m) <- rownames(data)
       A1BG  A1CF   A2M AAGAB  AAMP
A1BG  1.000 0.477 0.477 0.477 0.383
A1CF  0.477 1.000 0.625 1.000 0.501
A2M   0.477 0.625 1.000 1.000 0.526
AAGAB 0.477 1.000 1.000 1.000 0.815
AAMP  0.383 0.501 0.526 0.815 1.000
```

I stumbled into this question by biostars, but you might get better question either in [support.bioconductor.org](https://support.bioconductor.org) or in [bioinformatics.stackexchange.com](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com).

---

If you want to compare the GO terms of each row, you can do this:

```
go_terms <- unique(unlist(data))
go_terms <- go_terms[go_terms != ""]
go_sim <- mgoSim(as.character(go_terms), as.character(go_terms),  semData=hsGO, measure="Wang", combine=NULL)
genes2go <- apply(data, 1, function(x){x[x != ""]})
```

Then you can iterate to the genes2go and use the `combineScore` to compare the rows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I have also used mgeneSim function and got results. But I I wish to apply mgoSim after removing " " entries from data for each row. If I apply mgoSim after removing "", I am getting different results.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by different results? Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example ? Or do you mean that you want to compare these genes only using those GO terms and omit other GO terms?

Comment: To be specific, I wish to compare GO terms among all the row vectors of the 'data' .

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand you. You want to compare GO terms to genes? Or compare GO terms between each row?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to compare GO terms between each row. If I run my code mentioned in question, I am getting this result: `mat=structure(c(1, 0.255, 0.194, 0.238, 0.089, 0.255, 1, 0.219, 0.328, 
0.188, 0.194, 0.219, 1, 0.414, 0.113, 0.238, 0.328, 0.414, 1, 
0.125, 0.089, 0.188, 0.113, 0.125, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))`

Comment: Can you please share me, how to find the combine score? What I was getting after executing my code, is different from yours. Actually, I have to iterate for `9076 x 9076` times.

Comment: Sorry, unless you post what you are hoping to achieve I won't be able to help you. You want to iterate 9076 by 9076 because you want to know what? What is all this code for? `combineScores` is a function of the GOSemSim package

Comment: I am sorry, if I am unable to explain you properly. Basically I want to create a matrix `mat[9076x9076]` that will contain mgoSim score of each row vector of my data containing 9076 rows and 870 columns. Each row vectors corresponds to GOTerms associated with 9076 genes. Row vectors contains null which I will not consider for comparisons.

Comment: And what is this column and row? If you have 9076 genes that are in rows, what are those 870 columns, also genes?? Could you please explain what is the purpose of this matrix? (Note that in the previous comment you mention a 9076x9076 matrix and later a 9076x870 matrix, I assume that the first matrix is wrong). Please finish the sentence: I want this matrix of 9076x870 to compare genes to...

Comment: The data matrix size is `9076 x 870`, where rows represents genes and columns represents associated GO Terms. Most of the genes have less than 870 GO Terms. Final result i.e. `mat` size is `9076 x 9076` which will contain the mgoSim score of all the 9076 genes pairwise.

Comment: Ok, then my first approach is your answer. You need all the ids of the genes and then let GOSemSim calculate the similarity between genes with the GO terms on the hsGO object

Comment: OK. Thanks for your reply. May be I am getting different results using nested for loop as I am not considering all columns with mgoSim. May be if I use all columns I will get same result as getting with mgeneSim.

Comment: Yes, if you use different GO terms you get different results.